# File requests do not go into OWIN (runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is true)

Tags: asp.net, owin, iis-express

I suddenly cannot get OWIN to handle requests that have static file extensions on them (e.g. mysite.com/index.html).  I have `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` set in my web.config and I have the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` package installed.

I created an MVCE to test this w/ the following steps

1. Create an new VS project.  Type ASP.NET, Empty Project
2. `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`
3. Add a `Startup.cs` file

`Startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MVCE.Startup.Startup))]
namespace MVCE.Startup
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app
                .Use(async (ctx, next) => {
                    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app in VS, I get "Hello World!" in my browser as expected for any path that doesn't have an extension on the URL.  As soon as I add an extension, I get a 404 from IIS and my OWIN code is never invoked.

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Here's my web.config from the MVCE:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

  </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
      type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a routing error.  When you have MVC or Web API installed in your project, they both automatically add routes that deal w/ "file like requests".  When you don't, you have to register the OWIN route yourself by adding

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapOwinPath("");
```

to your `Startup.cs` file.